# Getting key from value in .Net collection

Tags: collections, .net-2.0, dictionary

I am using a StringDictionary to store key value pairs. I need to use the keys and values interchangeably i.e. I should be able to get the key from the value as in my case the values will be distinct.

Is there a direct way I could do it (without looping)? Or if there is any other collection I could use to achieve this?

Currently I am looping:

```
public String GetKeyFromValue(string value)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in instance)
            { 
                if (String.Equals(kvp.Value, value))
                    return kvp.Key;
            }

            throw new Exception ("Key not found in FilterControlMapping");
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: changed tags, since it is not asp.net specific

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting key of value of a generic Dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

You basically need to use two dictionaries encapsulated into one.

There are already implementations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255341/getting-key-of-value-of-a-generic-dictionary/255630#255630) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268321/bidirectional-1-to-1-dictionary-in-c/268545#268545) in other Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: That would mean double the memory, wouldn't it?

Comment: The memory of what, exactly? You'd still only have the actual *objects* once (assuming we're talking about reference types), because each collection would just have references to the real values. Yes, the space required for the book-keeping etc would be doubled, but that's the price you pay for being able to look up both ways.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is two dictionaries.

D1 < Key, Value >
D2 < Value, Key >

You would be repeating your data though. But you could search both keys and values this way.

Answer (score 0):

This would also be possible using Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sd = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string sKey = sd.Single(kvp => kvp.Value.Equals("A value")).Key;
```

Note that the Single method will throw if the value occurs more than once. You could use First or even FirstOrDefault.

Edit:
As Jon Skeet commented this is still looping. The links he posted to a linked dictionary provide the solution.

Comment: That's *effectively* looping though, i.e. the complexity is O(n) instead of the desirable O(1).

Comment: Can I use => operator in 2.0?

Comment: No, you can't use the lambda expression. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556425/predicate-delegates-in-c on how to achieve the same in 2.0
Though do note Jon Skeet's comment. This will still loop!

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is to use Dictionary instead of StringDictionary as its obselete..
you can find out more about this here:
[StringDictionary vs Dictionary<string, string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627716/stringdictionary-vs-dictionarystring-string/627733#627733)
regarding retrival you should go with linq internally it is using loops but still its much cleaner way..

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. I had actually migrated from Dictionary<string, string> to StringDictionary. Time to revert back :)