# VB.NET StringDictionary wont save as setting

Tags: vb.net

I have created a new user setting called `TheList` as a `System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.TheList Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.TheList = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary
    End If

    My.Settings.TheList.Add("Not", "Working")
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

However, for some reason `My.Settings.TheList` is actually always "nothing" and my dictionary entry is never saved.

Comment: FWIW, `StringDictionary` is a fairly early (in .NET terms) way of doing this - since generics have been around, it would be [more normal to use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627716/stringdictionary-vs-dictionarystring-string).

Comment: Look in the Output window or use Debug > Exceptions > tick CLR exceptions.  The FileNotFoundException you see is normal.  The InvalidOperationException is not, StringDictionary is not serializable.  A generic Dictionary is not either.  XML serialization is just rather lame.

Comment: @JamesThorpe When working with VB.NET settings, that's [what you get](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w83v3.png). There is 'Browse...', but you cannot browse for a generic type.

Comment: If you put that code somewhere else, like a button click you will get a `ConfigurationException: Configuration system failed to initialize`.  Settings works best on simple types and you cannot add any type, esp Dictionaries, to it.  Create a sensible type and serialize it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that saving a dictionary just isn't supported. Instead, I decided to serialize it on my own using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941122/4506174). Works like a dream.